# Insert data by batch?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need a code where the user (after pasting data in a datasheet), when he clicks a button, the data will be inserted in a table (I was thinking of using an SQL statement here). In addition to that, one of the fields in that table will have to be calculated using the DCount function. So I need to calculate that per record. Let me know if the idea is not clear and I need to explain further. Also, if there are better ideas out there, do tell. Thanks!

Comment: Explain datasheet pasting: the user uses data from Excel, for example?

Comment: yes, data from Excel will be pasted to the Access datasheet. i kind of solved it though. turns out, there is a problem when data is pasted from excel to access. you have to use the clipboard to paste the data to access.

Comment: Why not just import the spreadsheet directly and avoid forcing the user to manually do so much work?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create some VBA to pull in the data from the spreadsheet, insert it into the table and then close down excel again. All in a button click

Take a look at the below for an example

```
Dim objApp As Excel.Application
Dim objBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim sSQL As String
Dim Path As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

 Set objBook = Workbooks.Add(Template:=SheetLocation)   'Your excel spreadsheet file goes here where "SheetLocation is typed
            Set objApp = objBook.Parent
                Set objSheet = objBook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name of sheet you want to View
                   objBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
                   objApp.Visible = True

            objApp.DisplayAlerts = False




    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
' connect to the Access database
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "INSERT YOUR TABLE NAME HERE", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
r = 2 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("INSERT THE TABLE FIELD TO DUMP DATA IN HERE") = Range("A" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("REPEAT AS ABOVE") = Range("H" & r).Value
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
    objApp.Quit
```

Comment: This doesn't do it in a batch, as requested in the original question, but row-by-row. It also makes no sense to me to automate Excel when you can get to the data via SQL as long as you use the appropriate connect string.